# Display multiple images on td at a single time using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to make a game in which there is an 8x8 table and a coin displays on them(more than at 10 positions at a time) for 3000milliseconds on different position simultaneously. The coin display should start at a click of "Start" button and it continues for 1minute. My problem is that I am not able to make a random function which generates images randomly on different positions.it is giving some error of appendchild undefined.I want my image to display randomly on different positions),Here what I've tried so far.I've just started learning JS so please don't judge my code

PS:I can't use any Jquery

```js
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
var tr = tbl.insertRow();
var td = tr.insertCell();
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = '<img src="coin.png" alt="coin.png" class="coin_img" id="coin_image">';
var img = document.getElementById("coin_image");


function tableCreate() {
  var body = document.body;
  var tbl = document.createElement('table');
  tbl.style.width = '730px';
  tbl.style.height = '650px';
  tbl.style.border = '4px solid grey';
  tbl.style.display = 'inline-block';

  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      var td = tr.insertCell();
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      td.appendChild(div);
      div.innerHTML = '<img src="coin.png" alt="coin.png" class="coin_img" id="coin_image">';
      td.style.border = '1px solid black';
      td.style.width = '85px';
      td.style.height = '75px';
    }
  }
  body.appendChild(tbl);

}

function onTimer() {
  var seconds = 60;

  function tick() {
    var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
    seconds--;
    counter.innerHTML = "<h1>Time Left:-" + "0:" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds) + "</h1>";
    if (seconds > 0) {
      setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    } else {
      alert("Game over");
    }
  }
  tick();
  setInterval(function() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64);
    td[randomNumber].appendChild(img);
  }, 3000);
}

function onRestart() {
  location.reload();
}
```

```css
.button_class {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
}

.btn {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color:
}

.coin_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  display: none;
}

.counter_div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="tableCreate()">
  <div class="button_class">
    <button type="button" name="start_button" class="start_button btn" id="st_button" onclick="onTimer()">Start</button>
    <button type="button" name="restart_button" class="restart_button btn" id="rs_button" onclick="onRestart()">Restart</button>
    <div class="counter_div" id="counter">
      <h1>Total Time:-1:00</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The error happens at this part  `td[randomNumber].appendChild(img);` and means that `td` doesn't exist. Perhaps add a unique ID to each cell, and use this ID to select the cell and add your content

Comment: I think the error is with img that it didn't find it not with td.

Comment: `cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined` -> this means `td[...]` doesn't exist

Comment: so what to do then?I have declared it globally also

Answer (score 1):

- Do not declare `td` globally;
- You can access random cell using [`getElementsByTagName` method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp), like 
  `var td = tbl.getElementsByTagName("td")[randomNumber]`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems here:

1. Your code gives `Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined` on following line in `onTimer()` function:

   ```
    td[randomNumber].appendChild(img);
   ```

   It's pretty clear that **td** here is `undefined`.

   You've declared 'td' twice.

   First time on the top which binds td globally,

   and Second time inside the nested `for loop`

   ```
   ...
   for(var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
    for(var j = 0; j < 8; j++){
       var td = tr.insertCell(); //<-- HERE
       var div = document.createElement('div');
       td.appendChild(div);
       div.innerHTML = '<img src="coin.png" alt="coin.png" class="coin_img" id="coin_image">';
       td.style.border = '1px solid black';
       td.style.width = '85px';
       td.style.height = '75px';
     }
   }
   ...
   ```

   The second declaration is limited to the 'functional scope' created by `tableCreate()` function. So while you're trying to append the image to td at randomly generated position, you're actually getting the global reference of "td"(which is just an empty element and not an array of elements). Even if you keep updating things on the global td in nested for loop, you'll end up with the last referenced value of td  in for loop
2. There's a bit of an issue with your random number generation. You are generating a random number between 0 to 63 and hoping this would put the image in one of the 64 td's you generated in `tableCreate()` function, right? Wrong! Here's why: **you didn't generate those 64 td's at once! Rather you generated 8 td's for each of the 8 tr's**. So what you actually need is:

   - Generate a random number from 0-7 to select a random row(tr)
   - Generate another random number from 0-7 to select a random column(td) in row you got from step-1.

Here's the [plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/5rw6tcRLh8bqocIaAoaI?p=preview)

Comment: Please add a demo, I understand everything that you try to say but can't find the solution for "td", because when i didn't declare it globally it giving me an error or of "td" is undefined.so i defined it globally

Comment: Where is the demo?

Comment: @naveendharni: updated the answer with link to demo.

Comment: I'm not really sure what kind of game you are looking to build, but I hope it'll serve as a reference!

Comment: The coin shows and hide after 3000milliseconds on multiple positions not at single(more than 10) and when user click on it it will create a counter to count the no. of correct and wrong answer.